# Open returns identical file-descriptor in different processes

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, tty

System: Ubuntu 12.04
Compiler: gcc (version: 4.6.3)

My idea is to write a client-server application to exchange data via the serial port.

But my problem is, when I execute the code-snippet below, open returns the same file descriptor
if I start two independent processes:

The first process opens "/dev/ttyS0".
The 2nd process opens "dev/ttyS1".

```
    ....
    serialPortDescriptor = open(portName,
                                O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_EXCL);
if (serialPortDescriptor == INVALID_SERIALPORT_DESCRIPTOR) {
    return SERIALPORT_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
}
    .....
```

Is it normal that open returns the identical file descriptor value for different devices/pathnames ("dev/ttyS1" and "dev/ttyS0" respecively) in two different processes/programs?

Comment: Every process has its own standard input, which is always file descriptor 0.  Similarly with standard output and standard error (1 and 2).  Any number of processes can have a file descriptor 3 open; typically, they will be open to many different files or devices, some for input only, some for output only, some for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally normal. [File descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is just an offset into in-kernel per-process open file table.

Comment: in some OS it may be that, in some other it may be something else, but what it is is not a unique ID, just unique to the process. I see that it is specifically linux here, but fd's are std lib and so may be implemented differently in different os's

Comment: Well, not really a library thing, more like kernel syscall interface.